# Probabilities of repeats when I pick again from the same list.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say i got 10 numbers, 1 to 10. And i pick 3 random numbers from this list. No repeats, order does not matter. And then i pick 3 numbers again, what are the chance of these 3 numbers would have exactly 1 number identical to when I first picked 3 numbers?

Comment: When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter which numbers you've picked at first, as long as the second group of numbers is chosen independently of it [to see a rigorous proof of this, apply the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)].

This means we can wlog assume that the first three numbers are $1, 2, 3$. There is a total of $\binom{10}{3}$ ways of choosing three numbers from ten, of which $\binom{3}{1}\binom{7}{2}$ will contain exactly one of the numbers $1, 2, 3$ and two contain only numbers from $4$ to $10$. This yields a probability of
$$\frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}} = \frac{21}{40} = 52.5\%.$$

Comment: Dom, that was a rly good answer, Ty.

Comment: How do you calculate (10/3) ?

Comment: With the definition of the binomial coefficient: $\binom{10}{3} = \frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}$.

Comment: Ah, and all the ways to assemble this new set of 3 numbers, with at just 1 identical to previous is basically 3·7·6?

Comment: You need to divide this number by $2$ since the order of the numbers from $4, \ldots, 10$ doesn't matter.

Comment: Why don't divide by 6

Comment: Why would you divide by $6$? I can't really say much more than the explanation in my answer.

Comment: Divide by 6 as in there are 6 ways to assemble 3 different numbers.

Comment: Math isn't a guessing game, please try to understand why the binomial coefficients appear in my solution.